# API - validating request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5

I am creating a simple API for uploading files from mobile app.

In my `routes/api.php` file I have a route defined:

```
Route::post("/file", 'UploadController@upload');
```

then in my controller I validate the request:

```
public function upload(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'file' => 'file',
            'type' => 'required|in:sign,photo',
        ]);

     // do something here....

}
```

When the request is correct (it passes the validation) everything works fine and Laravel returns JSON response.

But if the request does not pass the validation, i.e. the `name` field is missing, Laravel returns 302 page and tries to redirect me to login page.

How can I return proper 40X/50X error with JSON message when validation fails, instead of 302 redirect page?

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest) for testing the API calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `validate` method returns a redirect for normal requests, and JSON for an AJAX request.

> The validate method accepts an incoming HTTP request and a set of validation rules. If the validation rules pass, your code will keep executing normally; however, if validation fails, an exception will be thrown and the proper error response will automatically be sent back to the user. In the case of a traditional HTTP request, a redirect response will be generated, while a JSON response will be sent for AJAX requests.

So you have several options, here are a couple:

- You can set the `X-Requested-With` header so Laravel thinks it is an AJAX request
- You can create your validator and call `fails()` on it and handle your response the way you want to:

---

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    // Custom Response
}
```

If you are only making an API, you may want to consider using [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com) instead as it is more finely tuned for that specific purpose. In addition, it's validation [defaults to returning a JSON response](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation).

Comment: Thanks, X-Requested-With did the trick. But still, it's a little bit weird that a request made from Insomnia is not properly recognised as AJAX request.